# Can I use Python's Decimal type with NumPy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I'm doing some calculations with Python3 and NumPy using float64 and sometimes, when I change my formulas a little (but mathematically equivalent), then I get slightly different results. I know that both formulas must produce the same result because they are actually the same, but floating-point calculations have their deficiencies and it shows. That's why I'd like to use Decimal.

As an example, the original formula would have the result `8.412265434e-6` and the changed formula would result in `8.412265425e-6` (last two digits are different). The difference is almost meaningless, but annoying (some equality checks do fail and no, I won't compare ± ε).

Since my formulas work with rational numbers only (divisions of integers), could I implement the formulas using NumPy and Decimal? If yes, are there things to be careful about?

I didn't find anything on the Internet about Decimal + NumPy.

EDIT: Should have been more specific... I'm calculating the mutual information of some variables, which requires logarithms (base 2 in my case).

Comment: Yes, if they're `object` arrays...

Comment: `decimal.Decimal` is also floating point, and even if it weren't, it would still be limited by the fact that it's decimal. `Decimal(2)/Decimal(3) != Decimal(1)/Decimal(3)*Decimal(2)`

Comment: Equality checks between floating point numbers are almost never a good idea.

Comment: Consider using [`.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) for this.

Comment: Why not use arbitrary-precision rational arithmetic instead?

Comment: *"...my formulas work with rational numbers only (divisions of integers)"* Then how about using [`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fractions.html)?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Good idea, forgot about them. `Fraction` doesn't seem to support logarithms directly though (needed for info theory; edited the question to mention this). I could prove my equalities by working with `Fraction` objects, just before converting to floats and applying `log`, although it might not be worth the effort.

Comment: "Fraction doesn't seem to support logarithms" - you said you were doing rational arithmetic only.

Comment: If fighting for ultimate precision, if you design the algorithm, using the numpy.dtype == object, where Fraction happens to get stores, shan't the logarithm part be taken care of by hard-coding a difference of plain np.log2() of the Fraction enumerator & denominator? That shall work even in numpy-vectorised forms thereof, shan't it?